# virtual host me redirige al dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp

estoy haciendo un proyecto con laravel y php, estoy montando el host virtual pero me redirige al dashboard.El codigo que genero laravel yo no lo toque no le hice nada por el momento!

```
extra/httpd-vhosts

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\public"
    ##ServerName projecto-instagram.local
</VirtualHost>

DRIVERS/HOSTS

127.0.0.1        projecto-instagram.local
::1              projecto-instagram.local
```

Comment: ¿A donde se supone que debería apuntar, al directorio `C:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\public`?

Comment: sisi tal cual. He leido algo del modo rewrite, puede ser que sea eso? ahora voy a revisar

Comment: Pero tu linea esta comentada `##DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\public"` lo mas probable es que tu **dashboard** este en la carpeta por defecto, o sea `C:\xampp\htdocs` y por eso es el que te carga. Deberías descomentar esa linea `DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\public"` quitando las **almohadillas** y reiniciar **xampp**

Comment: Lo del **mod_rewriter** si es necesario, esto hará que cargue correctamente tú `.htaccess` de **Laravel**. Lo habilitas agregando la linea `RewriteEngine on` y también `AllowOverride All`  allí en tu configuración

Comment: uhh mil gracias, era esoo! no me di cuenta, estaba comentada!!!muchas gracias bro!

Comment: Por nada..!! jaja suele suceder